# How to edit attachment with media-upload.php?

Tags: uploads, attachments

I'm looking to edit an attachment and I'm trying to supply a link to the existing preview image.

```
<a href="media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true&" class="thickbox" title="Edit Image" onclick="return false;" class="thickbox">
<img src="<?php echo $src_output; ?>" class="preview-upload"/>
</a>
```

I tried adding a **post_id** argument to the href but the thickbox only shows the media-upload box for a new upload. How can I edit an existing image using a link on the preview image?

```
<a href="media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true&post_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" ...
```